# How to monitor Dockerized Nodejs application through NewRelic?

Tags: node.js, docker, amazon-ecs, newrelic, newrelic-platform

I am planning to run my Nodejs application on AWS ECS. How can I monitor Node application through NewRelic which is running in a container(ECS)? How can I integrate newrelic.jar in Dockerfile?

Answer (score 1):

You can install it just like you would in any other system. There's a step-by-step tutorial [available](https://discuss.newrelic.com/t/relic-solution-what-you-need-to-know-about-new-relic-when-deploying-with-docker/52492) that essentially boils down to:

```
FROM tomcat
RUN mkdir -p /usr/local/tomcat/newrelic/logs
RUN useradd tomcat
RUN chown -R tomcat /usr/local/tomcat/newrelic/logs
ADD ./newrelic/newrelic.jar /usr/local/tomcat/newrelic/newrelic.jar
ADD ./newrelic/newrelic.yml /usr/local/tomcat/newrelic/newrelic.yml
```

and

```
version: ‘3’
services:
    web:
        build: .
        ports:
            - “8080:8080”
        environment:
            - TOMCAT_USERNAME=tomcat
            - TOMCAT_PASSWORD=tomcat
            - JAVA_OPTS=-javaagent:/usr/local/tomcat/newrelic/newrelic.jar
```

There's even more detailed information in the [docs](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/agents/java-agent/additional-installation/install-new-relic-java-agent-docker).

Comment: For Node I get error that it's unsupported because it needs systemd which is not available on docket containers